# variable object in c#

Tags: c#, variables, object, typeof

i have a class called gameObject and one of it's properties in called `component` and is of type `object`:

```
public object component;
```

and i'm trying to use this `object` to act as an object that can hold object of any class you give it. for example

```
unit c = new unit(...)
gameObject test = new gameObject(...)
test.component = c;
```

and i want to use the c object through the component object. for example

```
if(test.component==typeof(unit))
    test.component.Draw();//draw is a function of the unit object
```

is this possible to do? and how do i do it?

Comment: What are the range of types you might assign as a component? Can you think of a common set of behaviors that they should have?

Comment: If you use generics you can make **component** a strongtyped property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's called casting. Like this:

```
if(test.component is unit)
  ((unit)test.component).Draw();
```

Answer (score 7):

`typeof(unit)` is an object too, and it is different from `component`. You should do `component.GetType()` instead:

```
if(test.component.GetType()==typeof(unit))
```

This does not check for derived types, but this does:

```
if(test.component is unit)
```

Still, this does not let you call `Draw` without casting. The easiest way to check and cast at the same time is as follows:

```
unit u = test.component as unit;
if (u != null) {
    u.Draw();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use an interface and make the unit class implement that interface. Define the Draw() method in the interface and declare the component as the type of the interface you defined.

```
public interface IDrawable
{
 void Draw();
}

public IDrawable component;

public class unit : IDrawable
...
```

Answer (score 3):

if (test.component is unit) ((unit)(test.component)).Draw();

Answer (score 1):

As others said - you can cast everything to and from `Object`. But you should use some base class of interface to make sure no one will send you `Int32` or some other unsuspected type.
But if all supported types have some common method, it's even better to put it in interface. So you can `Draw()` anything without casting, not even wondering what it really is.

Variant with empty interface just enforcing proper type:

```
interface IComponent
{
}
class unit : IComponent
{
    //...
}
class enemy : IComponent
{
    //...
}
class gameObject
{
    IComponent component;//now only objects inheriting IComponent can be assigned here

    public void DrawComponent()
    {
        unit u = component as unit;
        if (u != null) {
            u.Draw();
        }
        enemy e = component as enemy;
        if (e != null) {
            e.DrawIfVisible();
        }
    }
}
```

Variant with interface declaring common features:

```
interface IDrawable
{
    void Draw();
}
class unit : IDrawable
{
    public void Draw(){;}
    //...
}
class enemy : IDrawable
{
    public void Draw(){;}
    //...
}


class gameObject
{
    IDrawable component;

    public void DrawComponent()
    {
        //now you don't need to care what type component really is
        //it has to be IDrawable to be assigned to test
        //and because it is IDrawable, it has to have Draw() method
        if (component != null) {
            component.Draw();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use specific behaviour of an object you have to cast it to its specific type.
Referencig it with an `object` variable you can use it only as an `object` instance.